# bind source-file in tmux on startup from bash

Tags: bash, tmux

I have a `.tmux.conf` file which binds a set of further tmux instructions when I press the correct keys (in this case, `Ctrl + b` followed by 'k'):

```
bind k source-file ~/.tmux/myfile
```

When I go into my tmux terminal and press `Ctrl + b` followed by `k`, it works fine, and the script in myfile runs as expected. I'm now trying to launch this all using a command in my `.bashrc` file by sending the keys to the tmux session once it has launched:

```
launch_things() {
    tmux new-session -d -s mysession
    tmux send-keys -t mysession C-b k
    tmux a -t mysession
}
```

However, this doesn't work. It's starting the tmux session, apparently benting the keys to it, then attaching to the session. I'm not sure if it's because I've done something wrong with the sending of the keys, or if it's not possible to send combinations of keys like this. Note that I *can* see the letter `k` on the screen when I attach, so the `send-keys` functionality is doing *something*.

Can anyone either tell me what I'm doing wrong, or suggest another way to launch my bound source-file (`~/.tmux/myfile`) from my bash script please?

P.S. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `send-keys` when sending strings does not try to interpret them for the prefix character. There is the command `send-prefix` but that behaves in the same way.

So the simple answer is to do `tmux source-file ~/.tmux/myfile` or perhaps the longer

```
tmux attach-session -t mysession\; source-file ~/.tmux/myfile\; detach-client
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you kind stranger ^_^